# Problem with gluOrtho2D()

Tags: opengl

I was trying to understand the [`gluOrtho2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) function. I have drawn 4 lines originating from the center reaching up to 4 corners of the screen.

You can follow the below code. `osize` is a variable which is used to set the parameters of `gluOrtho2D`. It will create a window of size `2*osize`.

If works fine when `osize` is 1. Lines reach the corners. But as I increase the value of `osize`, the length of the lines decreases (cross becomes smaller and does not cover the whole screen). But I think it should reach the corner.

```
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    //glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);

    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    float osize = 1.2;
    //glOrtho(-osize*1.0, osize*1.0, osize*1.0, -osize*1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    gluOrtho2D(-osize*1.0, osize*1.0, osize*1.0, -osize*1.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
       glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
       glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
       glVertex2f(-osize*1.0, -osize*1.0);
       glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
       glVertex2f(-osize*1.0, osize*1.0);       
       glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
       glVertex2f(osize*1.0, -osize*1.0);
       glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
       glVertex2f(osize*1.0, osize*1.0);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();  //includes glFlush();
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you resetting the projection matrix to the identity anywhere?  If not, all the `gluOrtho2D()` calls will stack on top of each other...

Comment: Ok got it. After setting the Projection matrix to Identity, it works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you inverted bottom with top? Ortho matrix will scale Y by 2 / (top - bottom), in your case a negative number.

Comment: In fact it only alters the order which lines will be drawn, as we normally think of Y increasing up.

Comment: The difference between the both is just that it will invert the y-axis.